# In cordova, how do I access a folder in persistent storage that starts with a '#' symbol using the File API?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to access a folder using the Cordova file API pluging which happens to begin with a hash/pound symbol, e.g. `/example/path/to/#folder`.

If you try to access this via `resolveLocalFileSystemURL()`, I am returned a `DirectoryEntry` which appears to have the correct path. However, calling `createReader()` and then `readEntries()` on this returns the files/directories for the directory above (including #folder itself) and not those that are actually in #folder. Presumably, something is going on with the fact that in a URL, anything after a hash symbol is a fragment part. But if this is the case, how do I properly access the entries of this folder? I have tried encoding the symbol with `\%23` or `%23` to no positive affect.

This behaviour has been found on Android but probably exists cross platform.

Comment: consider filling an issue on issues.cordova.io

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10317